# PHP login page with ldap authentication (usergroups)

Tags: php, html, ldap

I have a PHP login page with LDAP authentication. The script connect successfully  to my LDAP server, and it is possible for me to log in with my credentials. 
But I want to make the script more specific. I Want that the script connect to specific user group in my AD. The usergroup is TEST_LDAP. And it located in OU=Groups,OU=BE,OU=Company,DC=wetnl. I have tried it, but without succes.
Here is the PHP script:

```
session_start();
$succes = TRUE;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
if ( isset($_POST['gebruikersnaam']) && isset($_POST['wachtwoord']))
{
    /* aanmelden via LDAP */
    $ds=ldap_connect("10.10.10.110"); // geef hier het ip-adres in van een geldige LDAP server!
    if(!$ds)
    {
        $succes = FALSE;
        $foutmelding = 'Geen verbinding met Active Directory';
    }

    if($succes === TRUE)
    {
        ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        $r=ldap_bind($ds, $_POST['gebruikersnaam'], $_POST['wachtwoord']);
        if($r)
        {
       $_SESSION['gebruiker_id'] = $row['GEBRUIKERID'];
       $_SESSION['aangemeld'] = TRUE;
       header("Location: index.php");
        }
        else
        {
      $succes = FALSE;
      $foutmelding = 'Inloggen is niet gelukt door ongeldige combinatie gebruikersnaam/wachtwoord.<br/>';
  }
  ldap_close($ds);
}
   }
   else
   {
   $error = 'Vul zowel gebruikersnaam als wachtwoord in om in te loggen.';
   }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actuall error? And how is your LDAP structured? And it looks like your user has to provide the full DN as username. Have you had a look at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592?

Comment: I have no error. But i want OU search base. I gonna try the script you added!